# How to re-call gateway API from catch statement after certain minutes when payment gateway is down?

Tags: c#, exception, payment-gateway, webapi

I would like to know is there is any way in c# if payment gateway is down we get exception in catch , can we again re-call payment gateway API  from catch after some milliseconds in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the Polly framework (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It provides a fault-handling library. You could define your own retry policy (eg: when calls to payment gateway throw a 502/500 etc) and it would retry in a time that is also configurable.

Comment: is there any inbuilt capabilities of c# .net to do same as this question was asked in interview of Capgemini India.

Comment: @MiralShah I am not sure if there is any inbuilt C# retry mechanism. You could create a custom library for your retry requirements. Polly is one of them.